# Return the same response from a different server

Tags: http, node.js

I would like to return the same response that I get from a different server.

I have two servers in my computer. One of them is listening at "127.0.0.1:4000" and the other is listening at "127.0.0.1:5000". I would like to response all request on the first server with responses on second server ("http://127.0.0.1:5000/"). No redirect, I need a kind of bypass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to proxy requests from the first server to the second one, and you can achieve that with [node-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) or [bouncy](https://github.com/substack/bouncy) for example.